# CSS backdrop effect - blur background of search bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make the background (only the search bar) to be a backdrop blur background without blurring the whole background image behind it.
[image: Here's a screenshot of search bar]

[image: Here's an example of what the background of the search bar should look like]

I've tried webkit `filter: blur` & `filter: blur`, but they both blur the whole body and not just make the transparent background of the search bar blurred.
Note: I'm not using a background image in the code below because I'll embed this code in an `iframe`, which the background before it will be an image.

EDIT: I have removed the domain name in the *ORIGINAL* code so it doesn't conflict in search results for that domain name. Thanks everyone for helping me fix this issue! You're amazing!

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank" />
    <base target="_blank" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitSearch() {
        var siteSearchUrl = "https://*DOMAIN_NAME*/_/search?query="; // Replace with your site's search URL
        var query = document.getElementById("search-query-input").value;
        var url = siteSearchUrl + query;
        if (typeof IE_fix != "undefined") {
          // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
          var referLink = document.createElement("a");
          referLink.href = url;
          document.body.appendChild(referLink);
          referLink.click();
        } else {
          window.open(url, "_blank");
        } // All other browsers
      }
      function searchKeyPress(e) {
        // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
        e = e || window.event;
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById("search-icon").click();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
    </script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 14px 6px 0 6px;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      #search-icon {
        margin: 4px 4px 4px 10px;
        padding: 8px;
        height: 24px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      #search-icon:hover {
        background: rgba(155, 153, 176, 0.2);
        border-radius: 100px;
      }
      #search-query {
        background: inherit;
      }
      body:before {
        background: inherit;
      }
      #search-query:before {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        filter: blur(10px);
      }
      #search-query {
        width: max-content;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 14px;
        color: #212121;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
        transition: 0.4s;
      }
      #search-query:hover {
        color: #212121;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),
          0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 24px;
      }
      #search-query-input {
        width: 60vw;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-stretch: normal;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 24px;
        border: 0;
        color: #000;
        background-color: transparent;
        cursor: text;
        margin-left: -5px;
        text-align: start;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      @media (max-width: 500px) {
        #search-query-input {
          width: 80vw;
        }
      }
      @media (min-width: 900px) {
        #search-query-input {
          width: 60vw;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="query" />
            <button id="search" onclick="submitSearch()">Search</button> -->
    <div id="search-query">
      <img
        id="search-icon"
        alt="Search"
        onclick="submitSearch();"
        src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        id="search-query-input"
        placeholder="Search"
        enterkeyhint="go"
        onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);"
        style="box-shadow: none"
        ;=""
      />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function submitSearch(){
      var siteSearchUrl = 'https://support.yssf.ml/_/search?query=';  // Replace with your site's search URL
      var query = document.getElementById("search-query-input").value;
      var url = siteSearchUrl + query
if(typeof IE_fix != "undefined") // IE8 and lower fix to pass the http referer
{
 var referLink = document.createElement("a");
 referLink.href = url;
 document.body.appendChild(referLink);
 referLink.click();
}
else { window.open(url,'_blank'); } // All other browsers
}
function searchKeyPress(e){
  // look for window.event in case event isn't passed in
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
  {
      document.getElementById('search-icon').click();
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:14px 6px 0 6px;
  background-color:transparent;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1563356/pexels-photo-1563356.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500');
  background-size:100vw;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#search-query{
  background: transparent;
  width:max-content;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:0;
  border-radius:14px;
  color: #212121;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:24px;
  transition:0.4s;
}
#search-query::before {
box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
filter: blur(10px);
}
#search-query:hover {
  color: #212121;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 
              0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 
              0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:24px;
  backdrop-filter:blur(3px);
}
#search-query-input {
  width:60vw;
  height:24px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height:24px;
  border:0;
  color:#000;
  background-color:transparent;
  cursor:text;
  margin-left:-5px;
  text-align:start;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#search-query-input:hover{
  color:white;
}
#search-icon {
  margin: 4px 4px 4px 10px;
  padding:8px;
  height:24px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#search-icon:hover {
  background: rgba(155,153,176, 0.2);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
#search-query-input:hover::placeholder{
  color:white;
}
@media (max-width:500px) {
  #search-query-input {
    width:80vw;
   }
}
@media (min-width:900px) {
  #search-query-input {
    width:60vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <base target="_blank">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="query" />
        <button id="search" onclick="submitSearch()">Search</button> -->
    <div id="search-query">
        <img id="search-icon" alt="Search" onclick="submitSearch();" src="data:image/png;base64,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">
        <input type="text" id="search-query-input" placeholder="Search" enterkeyhint="go" onkeypress="return searchKeyPress(event);" style="box-shadow:none" ;="">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sections {
  background-image: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/3293148/pexels-photo-3293148.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940);
  background-size:100vw;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 15vh;
}
.search-bar {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 2vh;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.search-bar:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgb(142, 141, 141);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
.search-text {
  padding: 4vh 8vh;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #424242;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.search-text:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.fa-search {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2dba9f6187.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Blur Background Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="sections">
                <div class="search-bar">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thank you! This very much answered my question! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `filter` on any page element. This may require you to duplicate the existing background into the `#search-query` Div (so that there is an image present to be blurred, it then appears like a blur of the original image behind it) but also try it with no background as a test. It's been a while since I used it but you may find that the blur applies to everything behind it regardless.

```
#search-query{
   filter: blur(10px);
}
```